# Find convergence and radius of convergence of series: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{3}}{2^{n^2}}x^{0.5n(n-1)}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Find convergence and radius of convergence of series:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{3}}{2^{n^2}}x^{0.5n(n-1)}.$$

I tried to use the d'Alembert and Cauchy theorem, but for some reason I don't get the right answer. Any tips will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Those tests typically assume you have $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$. Probably the error is caused by the fact that here $a_n\ne n^3/2^{n^2}$.

Comment: I think you should tell us the wrong answer you got, and how you got it. And since you think you know the right answer you should tell us that as well.

Comment: I got an answer that the series converges on (-∞; ∞), but my teacher marked it as incorrect.